# Why is Control+Option+Space not opening my select dropdown?

Tags: html, google-chrome, accessibility, voiceover

I have a Select element like this:

```
<select name="dropdown">
    <option value="1" selected="">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Using Chrome with VoiceOver enabled on a Mac, if I use Space, dropdown opens, but if I use Control+Option+Space dropdown doesn't open. How can I solve this?

Comment: i presume you're on a mac since you mentioned 'option'?  on a pc, `alt+downarrow` opens the `<select>` element.  you can sometimes use 'option' as a replacement for 'alt' on a mac so perhaps `option+downarrow` will work.  i don't have a mac at the moment so can't try it.

Answer (score 5):

A lot can change about this answer depending on a few things.

I'm going to guess you're using a Mac (as @slugolicious pointed out) and also guess you're using VoiceOver since <kbd>Control+Option</kbd> keys usually aren't available unless you're using a screen reader.

In Safari and Firefox using Voiceover to open a select menu with <kbd>Control+Option+Space</kbd> works, so my last guess is that you are using Chrome+VoiceOver. If this is the case, there's not much you can do as it's a problem with Chrome not working well with VoiceOver. If you do try to fix it for Chrome it will probably cause problems in other browsers where the key commands do work.

Most users using VoiceOver will be using Safari as their browser of choice so they won't run into the issue, and those not using Safari will be use the the quirkiness of their browser and VoiceOver.

Comment: Yes you are right, I am using Voice over on Chrome in Mac.